# Common validation rules for different classes

Tags: c#

I have a query regarding validations. Let say i am having more than 1 classes and i want to do validation in following way -

class1 - 1st propertty should be mandatory
class2 - 2nd propertty should be mandatory
class3 - 1st propertty should be mandatory

so can i write some thing common so that i should not be writing code like null check for three classes. i mean i do not want to repeat null check for 3 different classes. there should be some common like if i pass instance and do the validation. can i do it ?

Comment: A class has no inherent rule- or validation-system. You have to code that yourself.

Comment: Could you please specify a bit more about the context and maybe provide an example? I find it hard to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: So what is the "First property"? please explain!

Comment: If you think in terms of ordered properties you should use a collection like `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Ok. let me explain a bit more. let say there are 2 classes. Employee,Student both classes are having property like - EmployeeName, StudentName. validation rule is that name property of both classes are mandatory. so i want that if i am having instances of these classes then i will pass that instance to common logic and my validation should run. i hope it should be clear now

Comment: Use attributes to mark down which are the properties needs to be validated, then use reflection/expression tree to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a model like this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.Validate(); // Exception

            Person p2 = new Person{Name = "Jack"};
            p2.Validate(); // OK

            Employee e1 = new Employee();
            e1.Validate(); // Exception

            Employee e2 = new Employee {Name = "John"};
            e2.Validate(); // Exception

            Employee e3 = new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 127};
            e3.Validate(); // Exception

            Employee e4 = new Employee {
                Name = "Gill",
                EmployeeNumber = 127
            };
            e4.Validate(); // OK
        }
    }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual void Validate() {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Name is not set");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Employee : Person {
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

        public override void Validate() {
            base.Validate();

            if (EmployeeNumber <= 0) {
                throw new NotSupportedException("EmployeeNumber is not set");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution is ok when inheritence is there. lets assume all classes are independant, no inheritance then what we can do?

Comment: If you want common functionality, you need common properties. This can be done with inheritance or by implementing interfaces. I don't understand why you wouldn't want to define a logical object model using inheritance though.

Comment: i tell you what i am saying. i want to use FileHelper(http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library. to use the library i have to define class. this class represents the file data. so if i am having 2 differnt files, so i will create 2 classes. these classes will hold the data from file. now i want to do the validation (common) like null check, field length. i hope i am clear now

Comment: so that's why there will not be any relation between 2 classes these classes are just to represent the file structure.